# Android toast: appending int to string causes line break

Tags: android, string, integer, toast

I'm trying to display a message stating what the user clicked, or pressed with their finger.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
   Toast.makeText(layout_4.this, "you clicked something with a number of " + Integer.toString(value), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

This displays (with say pressing box 4)

you clicked something with a number of
4

How can I get it to not add a line break before the number?

Comment: Have you tried to just do `"you clicked something with a number of " + value`? Do you get the line break with that, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a shot to `String.format("you clicked blah blah blah %1$d", value)` it always works for me. Plus this way you make it possible to pull that String from the strings.xml.

Comment: %d is for integers. %f is for floats. %s is for strings. And if you want to add more placeholders, you'll have to enumerate them (%1 at the beginning).

Answer (score 1):

Toasts do not specifically break before a number.

Try replacing your number with a single 'W' and you should see the same line break before the 'W'.

Three simple ideas : 
- Theme your Toast using a smaller font size
- Shorten the text message : "You clicked number " + ...
- Lengthen the text message so that it doesn't look weird to have only a number on the second line : "You have just clicked on the item numbered 4. Thank you !"